# useEffect not working in useFrameApi onReady event

Tags: javascript, reactjs, youtube-api

Im trying to change the url of the video dynamically using a useEffect Hook and i dont want to use third party library, so i have done this script, when i changing the url, the youtubeId state is well update but no new video is load in the player.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";

const Y = () => {
  const [youtubeId, setYoutubeId] = useState("ZPt9dJw1Dbw");

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!window.YT) {
      // If not, load the script asynchronously
      const tag = document.createElement("script");
      tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";

      // onYouTubeIframeAPIReady will load the video after the script is loaded

      window.onYouTubeIframeAPIReady = loadVideo;

      const firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
      firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);
    } else {
      loadVideo();
    }

    function loadVideo() {
      console.log(youtubeId);
      let player = new window.YT.Player(`youtube-player-${youtubeId}`, {
        videoId: youtubeId,
        events: {
          onReady: (event) => {
            event.target.playVideo();
            event.target.loadVideoById({
              videoId: youtubeId
            });
          }
        }
      });
    }
    //
  }, [youtubeId]);

  const foo = () => {
    setYoutubeId("ZrNqjSCfL8E");
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <div id={`youtube-player-${youtubeId}`} />
      <button onClick={foo}>change video</button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Y;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have done most of work correct. If you go through youtube Iframe api they set global `var`. It means you have to do some changes.

1. define `player` variable outside.
2. According to your code it will retrying to set `new window.YT.Player` object in variable but that's not how Iframe api work. Once its set in your `player` object. It will give another useFull function for doing that(you can find in there docs).

Here is full code:

```
import { useEffect, useState, useCallback } from "react";
import "./styles.css";
// import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
let player;

const Y = () => {
  const [youtubeId, setYoutubeId] = useState("ZPt9dJw1Dbw");

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!window.YT) {
      // If not, load the script asynchronously
      const tag = document.createElement("script");
      tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";

      // onYouTubeIframeAPIReady will load the video after the script is loaded

      window.onYouTubeIframeAPIReady = loadVideo;

      const firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
      firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);
    } else {
      loadVideo();
    }

    function loadVideo() {
      if (!player) {
        player = new window.YT.Player(`youtube-player-${youtubeId}`, {
          videoId: youtubeId,
          events: {
            onReady: (event) => {
              event.target.playVideo();
              event.target.loadVideoById({
                videoId: youtubeId
              });
            }
          }
        });
      }
      if (player && player.loadVideoById) {
        player.loadVideoById({ videoId: youtubeId });
      }
    }
    //
  }, [youtubeId]);

  const foo = () => {
    setYoutubeId("ZrNqjSCfL8E");
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <div id={`youtube-player-${youtubeId}`} />
      <button onClick={foo}>change video</button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Y />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Here is the demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/async-smoke-084n6